# How to raise list controls SelectedIndexChanged event in codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to raise the SelectedIndexChanged event of an asp.net List control in a codebehind using C#?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're asking how to manually fire the event so that it can run whatever logic is attached: **don't**.

Your event handlers should be slim.  If you need to perform the same operation from multiple places, then extract that functionality into its own method and have the event handler invoke that.  For example:

```
private void CountryListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateStates(ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text);
}

private void UpdateStates(string country)
{
    StateListBox.DataSource = GetStates(country);
    StateListBox.DataBind();
}
```

Now instead of trying to fire the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, you just invoke the method that this event handler refers to, i.e.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateStates("USA");
}
```

Don't put complex logic in event handlers and try to raise those events from unexpected places.  Instead, put the complex logic in its own method, so that you can perform the *associated actions* from elsewhere.

Comment: You are correct, in my own code I would definitely do it this way, I am trying to fix this application that is someone elses code base that is now my steaming pile and have tight deadlines to boot. lol.

Answer (score 4):

It is raised automatically.

- Go in the Events section, `lightening
  bolt` in properties window

[alt text http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/6100/listbox.jpg](http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/6100/listbox.jpg)

- double click the place holder next to
  event. This is what you will get.

> protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>        {
>        }

if you want to raise this event from another code block then, call

> ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender,
>   e);

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is more than just executing the code behaviour coded for the selected index (like listed in the previous answer), the short answer is there is no easy way. You can write a simple code that on prerender or render to explicitly define the control id variable in your rendered HTML and then  use javascript to set the selected index. This will cause the postback that trigger the event. Alternatively you can register an ajax call back method and have the client calls that either when some event happened or by automatic timer.